ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when opening a file in Download in a NativeScript Android app
I have an Angular NativeScript application that needs to download a file from a service, save it in Downloads, and open the file in the device's native viewer.  The app supports multiple file types including TXT, PDF, JPG, PNG, and TIF. The file is saving in the Download directory just fine and I'm getting the OS prompt for what app top open it in.  Whichever one I choose, usually Chrome, I'm getting an ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND response when using Utils.openFile(path).  This is on an Android emulator, there are no errors in the console or logcat.
Relevant AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="2023082201"
    android:versionName="0.0.0"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="34"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="31" tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"
            />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>

Code.ts
public async openFile(): Promise<void> {
    this.pageloader.show();
    const data: Blob = await firstValueFrom(this.myService.GetFile(params));
    try {
        let filePath = '';
        if (isAndroid) {
            filePath = this.writeFile_Android(data, doc.name);
        } else {
            filePath = this.writeFile_iOS(data, doc.name);
        }
        if (filePath) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.openFileFromPath(filePath);
                this.pageloader.hide();
            }, 500);
        } else {
            this.pageloader.hide();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('openFile error');
        this.pageloader.hide();
        console.error(e);
    }
}
private writeFile_Android(fileData: Blob, fileName: string): string {
    try {
        fileName = fileName.replace(/\//g, '-');
        fileName = fileName.replace(/ /g, '-');
        fileName = fileName.replace(/:/g, '-');

        const folder = Folder.fromPath(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
            ).getAbsolutePath()
        );

        const blob = (Array as any).create('byte', fileData.size);
        for (let i = 0; i < blob.length; i++) {
            blob[i] = (fileData as any)._buffer[i];
        }

        let docFile: fileSystem.File = folder.getFile(fileName);
        docFile.writeSync(blob);

        return docFile.path;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('writeFile_Android error');
        console.error(e, e.stack);
        return null;
    }
}
// import { Utils } from '@nativescript/core';
private openFileFromPath(path: string) {
    console.log(`path: ${path}`);
    // content://com.[company].[product].local.provider/external/Download/Text-Document.txt
    try {
        let opened = Utils.openFile(path);
        if (!opened) {
            console.error(`download file not opened '${path}'`);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('openFileFromPath error');
        console.error(e, e.stack);
    }
}

Versions
Angular CLI: 16.2.16
Node: 18.15.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.3.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.13
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.16 (cli-only)
@ngtools/webpack                14.2.13
@schematics/angular             16.2.16 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.8.4
zone.js                         0.12.0

Frankly I'm at a loss on what to try.  Four members of my team spent six hours on it and only got the file saving to Download.  This code worked and was released months ago.  I'm expecting the file to be vied in the system viewer.
